# Trying to use ResourceBundle to fetch messages from external file

Tags: java, internationalization

Essentially I would like to have a messages.properties files external to the jar files in my application. So that users can add languages and edit the files easily if my translations are wrong

at the moment i use

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("package.MessageBundle");
```

But i would like to do something like this

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("lang/MessageBundle");
```

Where lang is a folder under my application installation directory.

1. is this a good idea (if not, why not)?
2. can someone point me in the right direction, or some sample code that does this

thanks

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put it elsewhere in an existing path covered by the classpath, or add its path to the classpath. This way you can access it the same way, but instead maintain it externally.

Answer (score 0):

The way `ResourceBundle` works is that the argument you pass to `getBundle` is the "basename". This basename will be suffixed with the locale that you're working with, e.g. `MessageBundle_en.properties`, `MessageBundle_fr.properties`. If you want a different Locale to your system default, then you pass the Locale is as an additional parameter to `getBundle()`.

So what you end up with is multiple language files in one directory, rather than a directory for each language.

So rather than

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("lang/MessageBundle");
```

you would do

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageBundle", locale); // locale corresponds to "lang"
```

I suppose you could do this by prefixing the basename with the language name, but you'd be losing much of the functionality that `ResourceBundle` does for you out of the box.

The "externalizing" part is largely irrelevant, since `ResourceBundle` operates off the classpath, it works regardless of whether it internal (e.g. a JAR file), or external (e.g. a directory).

Comment: lang is just a static folder called lang, not a folder for each language. sorry for the confusion